# Input iOS GPS Variable into JSON/oAUTH request

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

I have an iOS app that redirects GPS coordinates into a Foursquare oAuth request. However, when I try and declare the variable "latitude" in the actual URL request, iOS is literally sending the word latitude and not the variable. How do I directly declare the variable (floating integer) for use instead of the word?

Also, in Xcode, it warns me that the variable latitude and longitude are both going unused in this implementation.

```
        float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
        float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

DECLARED INTO

```
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"latitude,longitude",@"ll", @"fast%food", @"query", nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're not really inserting the values into the dictionary. Instead, use:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{"latitude" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:latitude], 
                             "longitude" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:longitude],
                              ...};
```